# How play method works at "NCD.L1.sample--lottery" contract?

Tags: nearprotocol, assemblyscript

Here is the contract repo. https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--lottery

I don't understand the play method here
https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--lottery/blob/2bd11bc1092004409e32b75736f78adee821f35b/src/lottery/assembly/lottery.ts#L11-L16

```js
 play(): bool {
    const rng = new RNG<u32>(1, u32.MAX_VALUE);
    const roll = rng.next();
    logging.log("roll: " + roll.toString());
    return roll <= <u32>(<f64>u32.MAX_VALUE * this.chance);
  }
```

I don't understand the winning process but I'm sure it is hidden inside this method. So can someone explain how this `play` method works in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the winning process we should take a look at the `play` method in the `lottery.ts` file in the contract.

https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--lottery/blob/2bd11bc1092004409e32b75736f78adee821f35b/src/lottery/assembly/lottery.ts#L11-L16

```js
    play(): bool {
        const rng = new RNG<u32>(1, u32.MAX_VALUE);
        const roll = rng.next();
        logging.log("roll: " + roll.toString());
        return roll <= <u32>(<f64>u32.MAX_VALUE * this.chance);
      }
```

There are a couple of things we should know about before we read this code.

- bool
- u32
- f64
- RNG<32>

**bool** means that our `play` method should only return true or false.

[**u32**](https://towardsdatascience.com/unsinged-signed-integers-and-casting-in-rust-9a847bfc398f#f4ce) is a 32-bit unsigned integer. It is a positive integer stored using 32 bits.

u8 has a max value of 255. u16 has a max value of 65535. u32 has a max value of 4294967295. u64 has a max value of 18446744073709551615. So, these unsigned integers can't be negative values.

[**f64**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.56.0/std/primitive.f64.html) is a number that has a decimal place. This type can represent a wide range of decimal numbers, like 3.5, 27, -113.75, 0.0078125, 34359738368, 0, -1. So unlike integer types (such as i32), floating-point types can represent non-integer numbers, too.

**RNG** stands for `Random Number Generator`. It basically gives you a random number in the range of `u32`. And it takes two parameters that define the range of your method. In that case, the range is between **1** and **u32.MAX_VALUE**. In other words, it is **1** and **4294967296**.
The next line creates a variable called `roll` and assigned it to the value of `rng.next()`.

So, what does `next()` do? Think `rng` as a big machine which only has one big red button on it. When you hit that big red button, it gives you a number that this machine is capable of producing. Meaning, every time you hit that button, it gives you a number between **1** and **u32.MAX_VALUE**

The third line is just about logging the `roll` into the console. You should see something like that in your console `roll: 3845432649`

The last line looks confusing at the beginning but let's take a look piece by piece.

Here, `u32.MAX_VALUE * this.chance` we multiply this max value with a variable called `chance` which we defined as **0.2** in the `Lottery` [class](https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--lottery/blob/2bd11bc1092004409e32b75736f78adee821f35b/src/lottery/assembly/lottery.ts#L5).

Then, we put `<f64>` at the beginning of this calculation because the result always will be a floating number due to **0.2**.

Then, we put `<32>` at the beginning of all to convert that floating number into **unsigned integer** because we need to compare it with the `roll` which is an **unsigned integer**. You can't compare floating numbers with unsigned integers.

Finally, if the `roll` less than or equals to `<u32>(<f64>u32.MAX_VALUE * this.chance)` this, player wins.